# Bottom Overflow Problem in Flutter Despite of Screen fixing(?!)

Tags: flutter

I was trying to make a responsive app that measure the screen height and than apply it's container's height according it. I split the app's page in (40%, 30% , 30%) portion, but the app showing the message "Bottom pixel overflow by 10.0 pixel".
And When I rotate the Scene, The middle portion container also show the same problem.

As A newbie, I Don't understand what is my wrong-doing or wrong-knowing?
Is the padding cause the problem?
And is there any simple or standard system to design a app responsive to various window ?

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'TravelApp';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        //appBar: AppBar(
        //centerTitle: true,
        //title: const Text(_title),
        //),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dynamic screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    dynamic screenwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      height: screenHeight,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [Color(0xFDEAEC), Colors.grey]),
      ),
      // Portion Started In The Column
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: screenHeight * 0.40, //40% of Screen height
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('../assets/firstpag.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: screenHeight * 0.30, //30% of Screen height
            color: Colors.green,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "Let's Get Started",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: screenwidth * 0.20,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 10,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: screenHeight * 0.30, //30% of Screen height
            color: Colors.red,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "Let's Get Started",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: screenwidth * 0.20,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 10,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use AspectRatio

Comment: wrap the first container under ```body```  with   ```SingleChildScrollView ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code above is that it is using a `padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)` which also means we're using 5px from the bottom and from the top as padding.

Therefore, the layout overflows by 10px.

A possible solution would be to either remove the padding or change it to horizontal-only, depending on the desired outcome:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
```

Full snippet code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'TravelApp';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        //appBar: AppBar(
        //centerTitle: true,
        //title: const Text(_title),
        //),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dynamic screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    dynamic screenwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      height: screenHeight,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5), // modified line
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [Color(0xFDEAEC), Colors.grey]),
      ),
      // Portion Started In The Column
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: screenHeight * 0.40, //40% of Screen height
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('../assets/firstpag.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: screenHeight * 0.30, //30% of Screen height
            color: Colors.green,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "Let's Get Started",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: screenwidth * 0.20,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 10,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: screenHeight * 0.30, //30% of Screen height
            color: Colors.red,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "Let's Get Started",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: screenwidth * 0.20,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          height: 4,
                          width: 10,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```